# Cucumber hooks are not running. I am using io.cucumber.java8

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, appium, ui-automation

I am trying to run steps required before and after the scenarios using Cucumber hooks, but the methods in hooks class are not running. Below is the hooks class.

Used dependencies :

<cucumber.version>6.11.0</cucumber.version>

```
  package com.neobank.hooks;

  import com.neobank.core.Driver;
  import io.cucumber.java8.En;

  public class ScenarioHooks implements En {
  public ScenarioHooks() {
    Before(Driver::startAppiumDriver);
    After(Driver::resetApp);
    After(Driver::stopChromeDriver);
    }
  }
```

Glue Path:

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber.html", 
    "json:target/cucumber.json"},
    features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
    glue = {"com.neobank.steps", "com.neobank.hooks"},
    tags = "@Onboardingtwo"
```

Comment: Is your hook class under the glue path?

Comment: Hi @AlexeyR. have updated the glue path above....

Comment: @RaghuK getting any error? I believe hooks class should not be extending(inheriting) to any other class. But you are implementing an interface so if you experience "Java invalid method" exception then you should not extend or implement anything.

Comment: Hi @NandanA not getting any error or exception, but code present in the methods mentioned above are not running.

Comment: Have you debugged? or tried by putting some print statements?

Comment: @NandanA. Yes I tried, statements not getting printed

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue here. Was trying to run the cucumber scenarios individually from feature files. If hooks are to be executed then we have to run using the runner file.